# phpfox ajax return empty

Tags: ajax, phpfox

I am getting no data while using ajax call, it works fine without ajax or if I send no any parameter in ajax.

Here is the URL
http://localhost/phpfox/index.php?do=/blog/search/keyword_lorem/zipcode_LS11%25206AU/rangevaluefrom_3/rangetype_0/submit1_1/search-id_9666aeaf80cd89b66b53f3e1af8c05fd/

The code for ajax is as

```js
$(this).ajaxCall('blog.tagsSearch','keyword='+tags+'&encode=1&zipcode=LS11%206AU&rangevaluefrom=3&rangetype=0&view=my','GET');



<?php

Phpfox::getComponent('blog.index', array(), 'controller');
$this->html('.column_wrapper', $this->getContent(false));

?>
```

Comment: please check if `function tagsSearch(){ }`  is defined inside `\module\blog\include\component\ajax\ajax.class.php`

Comment: It was not defined, Its fixed now.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check inside `\module\blog\include\component\ajax\ajax.class.php`

there `function tagsSearch(){ }` is defined

```
class Blog_Component_Ajax_Ajax extends Phpfox_Ajax
{
    // ... other codes

    public function tagsSearch(){ 
       // ... codes for tag search
    }

    // ... more codes
 }
```